# Hide multiple <div> on page loaded by ajax call till button click

Tags: javascript

I have already seen similar threads on SO.

I have `index.php` on button click `url.php` get loaded through ajax in the `<div>` present in `index.php`

On `url.php` there are couple of `<div>`. I want some of them to be visible only after button click. I got solution for this.
**But only 1 div become visible rest hidded** Is it due to `z-index` property?

index.php:

```
<script>
$("#load_url").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"url.php",
        success:function(response) {
            $("#view_port").html(response);
            $("#load_url").hide();
        }
    }); 
});

function show2() {
   //alert("hi");
    document.getElementById("txtHint").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("rateit99").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("cb1").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

url.php

```
   <body style="height: 560px">

      <div class="rateit bigstars" id="rateit99"  style="z-index: 1; display:none;" ><b>Rate Me </b></label>
      </div>
     <label2 color="red" id="l1" style="z-index: 1; left: 438px; display:none; top: 180px; position:absolute" ><b><u>Add comment</u> </b></label2>

    <form action="data.php" method="POST" onsubmit="showUser(this, event)">
    <div style="z-index: 1; left: 420px; top: 40px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px">           
    <label>Enter URL: <input type="text" id="t1" value="http://www.paulgraham.com/herd.html" name="sent" style="width: 400px; height:40px;" ></label><br/>
    </div>
    <div style="z-index: 1;" >  <button onclick="show2();"> Get Sentiment </button>         
    </div>
    </form>
    <div style="z-index: 1; left: 720px; top: 110px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px">   
    </div>
    <h4>

   <div id="txtHint" align="justify" style="z-index: 3;  ">         </h4>
         </div>
<div class="fb-comments" id='cb1'"  ></div>
</div>
      </body>
```

when button **Get Sentiment** clicked. Only **id="txtHint"** and lable **Rate me** appears.

**cb1, rateit99** remains invisible, what is the bug here?

Link to full code:

index.php
http://codetidy.com/6857/

url.php
http://codetidy.com/6858/

Comment: There are multiple errors in the markup you provided; for instance - `</label>` tag in line 1 has no starting tag but only ending, Quotation marks are improper in this line `<div class="fb-comments" id='cb1'"  ></div>` and `<div>` tag is not a valid child tag for an `<h4>` tag. And `<label2>` doesn't seems to be valid HTML tag either.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a answer but because I can not comment- 
Actually this is happening because of css conflicts. try to give display none every such element through class and then apply direct style as ur doing. you can also use !important to give higher preference.

Comment: can you please elborate I could not understand what you said!

Comment: If u can provide a jsfiddle for your problem we can help you better.

Comment: I have added the link to full code. IF you can review it!
I investigated a lot. But could not find why content from url.php to index.php not getting loaded. May some technical bug!